# How to improve programming skill for computation?

Tags: c++

I'm physics student and write codes for simulation of electromagnetic waves.I post one of my codes here and my question is how can I improve my code.(not the speed )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

#define IE 100
#define JE 100
#define KE 100
double ***alloc3d(int l, int m, int n) {
double *data = new double [l*m*n];
double ***array = new double **[l];
for (int i=0; i<l; i++) {
    array[i] = new double *[m];
    for (int j=0; j<m; j++) {
        array[i][j] = &(data[(i*m+j)*n]);
    }
}
return array;
}



int main()

{
//////////////////////declartion/////////////////////////////
int const NFREQS=100,ia=7,ja=7,ka=7;
double const pi=3.14159;
int i,j;
double ***gax=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);
double ***gay=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);
double ***gaz=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);
double ***gbx=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);
double ***gby=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);
double ***gbz=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);
double ***dx=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);
double ***dy=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);
double ***dz=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);
double ***ex=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);
double ***ey=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);
double ***ez=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);
double ***sx=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);
double ***sy=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);
double ***sz=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);
double ***hx=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);
double ***hy=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);
double ***hz=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);
double ***ix=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);
double ***iy=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);
double ***iz=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);
double ***idyl=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);
double ***ihyl=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);

double*** idxl=new double**[ia];
double*** idxh=new double**[ia];
double*** ihxl=new double**[ia];
double*** ihxh=new double**[ia];
for(i=0;i<ia;i++)
{
    idxl[i]=new double *[JE];
    idxh[i]=new double *[JE];
    ihxl[i]=new double *[JE];
    ihxh[i]=new double *[JE];
    for(j=0;j<JE;j++)
    {
        idxl[i][j]=new double [KE];
        idxh[i][j]=new double [KE];
        ihxl[i][j]=new double [KE];
        ihxh[i][j]=new double [KE];
    }
}

double***idzl=new double**[IE];
double***idzh=new double**[IE];
double***ihzl=new double**[IE];
double***ihzh=new double**[IE];
for(i=0;i<IE;i++)
{
    idzl[i]=new double *[JE];
    idzh[i]=new double *[JE];
    ihzl[i]=new double *[JE];
    ihzh[i]=new double *[JE];
    for(j=0;j<JE;j++){
        idzl[i][j]=new double [ka];
        idzh[i][j]=new double [ka];
        ihzl[i][j]=new double [ka];
        ihzh[i][j]=new double [ka];
    }
}
double *gi1=new double [IE];
double *gi2=new double [IE];
double *gi3=new double [IE];
double *gj1=new double [JE];
double *gj2=new double [JE];
double *gj3=new double [JE];
double *gk1=new double [KE];
double *gk2=new double [KE];
double *gk3=new double [KE];
double *fi1=new double [IE];
double *fi2=new double [IE];
double *fi3=new double [IE];
double *fj1=new double [JE];
double *fj2=new double [JE];
double *fj3=new double [JE];
double *fk1=new double [KE];
double *fk2=new double [KE];
double *fk3=new double [KE];
int    l,n,m,k,ic,jc,kc,nsteps,numsph,npml,ib,jb,kb,ixh,jyh,kzh,ke,percent;
double xn,xxn,xnum,xd,curl_e,curl_h,freqi,freqf;
double *ez_inc=new double [JE];
double *hx_inc=new double [JE];
double t0,spread,pulse;
double *freq=new double [NFREQS];
double *arg=new double [NFREQS];
double***real_pt=new double**[NFREQS];
double***imag_pt=new double**[NFREQS];
for(m=0;m<NFREQS;m++)
{
    real_pt[m]=new double *[IE];
    imag_pt[m]=new double *[IE];
    for(i=0;i<IE;i++){
        real_pt[m][i]=new double [JE];
        imag_pt[m][i]=new double [JE];
    }
}
double***real_pt_sx=new double**[NFREQS];
double***imag_pt_sx=new double**[NFREQS];
for(m=0;m<NFREQS;m++)
{
    real_pt_sx[m]=new double *[IE];
    imag_pt_sx[m]=new double *[IE];
    for(i=0;i<IE;i++){
        real_pt_sx[m][i]=new double [JE];
        imag_pt_sx[m][i]=new double [JE];
    }
}
double***real_pt_sy=new double**[NFREQS];
double***imag_pt_sy=new double**[NFREQS];
for(m=0;m<NFREQS;m++)
{
    real_pt_sy[m]=new double *[IE];
    imag_pt_sy[m]=new double *[IE];
    for(i=0;i<IE;i++){
        real_pt_sy[m][i]=new double [JE];
        imag_pt_sy[m][i]=new double [JE];
    }
}
double***real_pt_sz=new double**[NFREQS];
double***imag_pt_sz=new double**[NFREQS];
for(m=0;m<NFREQS;m++)
{
    real_pt_sz[m]=new double *[IE];
    imag_pt_sz[m]=new double *[IE];
    for(i=0;i<IE;i++){
        real_pt_sz[m][i]=new double [JE];
        imag_pt_sz[m][i]=new double [JE];
    }
}

double *real_in=new double[NFREQS];
double *imag_in=new double[NFREQS];
double *amp_in=new double[NFREQS];
double *phase_in=new double[NFREQS];
ic=IE/2;
jc=JE/2;
kc=KE/2;
ddx=2e-9;
dt=ddx/6e8;
epsz=8.8e-12;
ib=IE-ia-1;
jb=JE-ja-1;
kb=KE-ka-1;
/////////////////////////////initilization///////////////////////
ez_low_m2=0;
ez_high_m2=0;
ez_low_m1=0;
ez_high_m1=0;
for(j=0;j<JE;j++){
    ez_inc[j]=0.0;
    hx_inc[j]=0.0;
    for(i=0;i<IE;i++){

    }}
for (k=0;k<KE;k++){
    for(j=0;j<JE;j++){
        for(i=0;i<IE;i++){
            ex[i][j][k]=0.0;
            ey[i][j][k]=0.0;
            ez[i][j][k]=0.0;
            sx[i][j][k]=0.0;
            sy[i][j][k]=0.0;
            sz[i][j][k]=0.0;
            ix[i][j][k]=0.0;
            iy[i][j][k]=0.0;
            iz[i][j][k]=0.0;
            dx[i][j][k]=0.0;
            dy[i][j][k]=0.0;
            dz[i][j][k]=0.0;
            hx[i][j][k]=0.0;
            hy[i][j][k]=0.0;
            hz[i][j][k]=0.0;
            gax[i][j][k]=1.0;
            gay[i][j][k]=1.0;
            gaz[i][j][k]=1.0;
            gbx[i][j][k]=0.0;
            gby[i][j][k]=0.0;
            gbz[i][j][k]=0.0;
            idyl[i][j][k]=0.0;
            ihyl[i][j][k]=0.0;
        }}}
for(i=0;i<ia;i++){
    for(j=0;j<JE;j++){
        for(k=0;k<KE;k++){
            idxl[i][j][k]=0.0;
            idxh[i][j][k]=0.0;
            ihxl[i][j][k]=0.0;
            ihxh[i][j][k]=0.0;
        }}}

for(i=0;i<IE;i++){
    for(j=0;j<JE;j++){
        for(k=0;k<ka;k++){
            idzl[i][j][k]=0.0;   
            idzh[i][j][k]=0.0;
            ihzl[i][j][k]=0.0;
            ihzh[i][j][k]=0.0;
        }}}
for(i=0;i<IE;i++){
    gi1[i]=0.0;
    fi1[i]=0.0;
    gi2[i]=1.0;
    fi2[i]=1.0;
    gi3[i]=1.0;
    fi3[i]=1.0;
}
for(j=0;j<JE;j++){
    gj1[j]=0.0;
    fj1[j]=0.0;
    gj2[j]=1.0;
    fj2[j]=1.0;
    gj3[j]=1.0;
    fj3[j]=1.0;
}
for(k=0;k<KE;k++){
    gk1[k]=0.0;
    fk1[k]=0.0;
    gk2[k]=1.0;
    fk2[k]=1.0;
    gk3[k]=1.0;
    fk3[k]=1.0;
}
for(n=0;n<NFREQS;n++){
    real_in[n]=0.0;
    imag_in[n]=0.0;
    amp_in[n]=0.0;
    phase_in[n]=0.0;
    for(j=0;j<JE;j++){
        for(i=0;i<IE;i++){
            real_pt[n][i][j]=0.0;
            imag_pt[n][i][j]=0.0;
            real_pt_sx[n][i][j]=0.0;
            imag_pt_sx[n][i][j]=0.0;
            real_pt_sy[n][i][j]=0.0;
            imag_pt_sy[n][i][j]=0.0;
            real_pt_sz[n][i][j]=0.0;
            imag_pt_sz[n][i][j]=0.0;
        }}}
lambdai=200e-9;
lambdaf=700e-9;
freqi=2e8/lambdai;
freqf=7e8/lambdaf;
for(i=0;i<NFREQS;i++){
    freq[i]=freqi-i*(freqi-freqf)/NFREQS;
}
for(n=0;n<NFREQS;n++){
    arg[n]=2*pi*freq[n]*dt;
}

//////////////////////////antena//////////////////////////

t0=20.0;
spread =6.0;
T=0.0;
cout<<"enter time -->";
cin>>nsteps;
ke=0;
////////////*******************FDTD*******************///////////////////////
for (n=1;n<=nsteps;n++){
    T=T+1;
    percent=T/nsteps*100;
    if (percent>=ke+1) {
        cout<<percent<<"%"<<endl;
    }
    ke=percent;



    /////////////////////source////////////////////
    pulse=exp(-.5*(pow((t0-T)/spread,2.0)));
    ez_inc[3]=pulse;
    //////////////////ABC//////////////////////////////////
    ez_inc[0]=ez_low_m2;
    ez_low_m2=ez_low_m1;
    ez_low_m1=ez_inc[1];
    ez_inc[JE-1]=ez_high_m2;
    ez_high_m2=ez_high_m1;
    ez_high_m1=ez_inc[JE-2];
    //////////////////////////update dx///////////////////////////////
    for(i=1;i<ia;i++){
        for(j=1;j<JE;j++){
            for(k=1;k<KE;k++){
                curl_h=(hz[i][j][k]-hz[i][j-1][k]-hy[i][j][k]+hy[i][j][k-1]);
                idxl[i][j][k]=idxl[i][j][k]+curl_h;
                dx[i][j][k]=x[i][j][k]+gj2[j]*gk2[k]*.5*(curl_h+gi1[i]*idxl[i][j][k]);
            }}}
    for(i=ia;i<=ib;i++){
        for(j=1;j<JE;j++){
            for(k=1;k<KE;k++){
                curl_h=(hz[i][j][k]-hz[i][j-1][k]-hy[i][j][k]+hy[i][j][k-1]);
                dx[i][j][k]=gj3[j]*gk3[k]*dx[i][j][k]+gj2[j]*gk2[k]*.5*curl_h;
            }}}
    for(i=ib+1;i<IE;i++){
        ixh=IE-i-1;
        for(j=1;j<JE;j++){
            for(k=1;k<KE;k++){
                curl_h=(hz[i][j][k]-hz[i][j-1][k]-hy[i][j][k]+hy[i][j][k-1]);
                idxh[ixh][j][k]=idxh[ixh][j][k]+curl_h;
                dx[i][j][k]=dx[i][j][k]+gj2[j]*gk2[k]*.5*(curl_h+gi1[i]*idxh[ixh][j][k]);
            }}}
    /////////////////////////update dy/////////////////////////////////
    for(i=1;i<IE;i++){
        for(j=1;j<JE;j++){
            for(k=1;k<KE;k++){
                curl_h=(hx[i][j][k]-hx[i][j][k-1]-hz[i][j][k]+hz[i-1][j][k]);
                idyl[i][j][k]=idyl[i][j][k]+curl_h;
                dy[i][j][k]=y[i][j][k]+gi2[i]*gk2[k]*.5*(curl_h+gj1[j]*idyl[i][j][k]);
            }}}


    ////////////////////////update dz///////////////////////////////////

    for(i=1;i<IE;i++){
        for(j=1;j<JE;j++){
            for(k=0;k<ka;k++){
                curl_h=(hy[i][j][k]-hy[i-1][j][k]-hx[i][j][k]+hx[i][j-1][k]);
                idzl[i][j][k]=idzl[i][j][k]+curl_h;
                dz[i][j][k]=gi3[i]*gj3[j]*dz[i][j][k]+gi2[i]*gj2[j]*.5*(curl_h+gk1[k]*idzl[i][j][k]);
            }}}
    for(i=1;i<IE;i++){
        for(j=1;j<JE;j++){
            for(k=ka;k<=kb;k++){
                curl_h=(hy[i][j][k]-hy[i-1][j][k]-hx[i][j][k]+hx[i][j-1][k]);
                dz[i][j][k]=gi3[i]*gj3[j];
            }}}
    for(i=1;i<IE;i++){
        for(j=1;j<JE;j++){
            for(k=kb+1;k<KE;k++){
                kzh=KE-k-1;
                curl_h=(hy[i][j][k]-hy[i-1][j][k]-hx[i][j][k]+hx[i][j-1][k]);
                idzh[i][j][kzh]=idzh[i][j][kzh]+curl_h;
                dz[i][j][k]=gi3[i]*gj3[j]*dz[i][j][k]+
            }}}
    ///////////////////////////////<<<<<<<<<incident dz>>>>>>>>>>>>>////////////////////////////

    ////////////////////////////source///////////////////////////

     pulse=exp(-.5*(pow((t0-T)/spread,2.0)));
     dz[ic][jc][kc]=pulse;



    ////////////////////////////////{{{{{{{{{{{update ex,ey,ez}}}}}}}}}}}}///////////////////////
    for(i=1;i<IE-1;i++){
        for(j=1;j<JE-1;j++){
            for(k=1;k<KE-1;k++){
                ex[i][j][k]=gax[i][j][k]*(dx[i][j][k]-ix[i][j][k]);
                ix[i][j][k]=ix[i][j][k]+gbx[i][j][k]*ex[i][j][k];
                ey[i][j][k]=gay[i][j][k]*(dy[i][j][k]-iy[i][j][k]);
                iy[i][j][k]=iy[i][j][k]+gby[i][j][k]*ey[i][j][k];
                ez[i][j][k]=gaz[i][j][k]*(dz[i][j][k]-iz[i][j][k]);
                iz[i][j][k]=iz[i][j][k]+gbz[i][j][k]*ez[i][j][k];
            }}}

    //////////////////////////////update hx///////////////////////////////////
    for(i=0;i<ia;i++){
        for(j=0;j<JE-1;j++){
            for(k=0;k<KE-1;k++){
                curl_e=(ey[i][j][k+1]-ey[i][j][k]-ez[i][j+1][k]+ez[i][j][k]);
                ihxl[i][j][k]=ihxl[i][j][k]+curl_e;
                hx[i][j][k]=fj3[j]*fk3[k]*hx[i][j][k]+fj2[j]*fk2[k]*.5*(curl_e+fi1[i]*ihxl[i][j][k]);
            }}}
    for(i=ia;i<=ib;i++){
        for(j=0;j<JE-1;j++){
            for(k=0;k<KE-1;k++){
                curl_e=(ey[i][j][k+1]-ey[i][j][k]-ez[i][j+1][k]+ez[i][j][k]);
                hx[i][j][k]=.5*curl_e;
            }}}
    for(i=ib+1;i<IE;i++){
        ixh=IE-i-1;
        for(j=0;j<JE-1;j++){
            for(k=0;k<KE-1;k++){
                curl_e=(ey[i][j][k+1]-ey[i][j][k]-ez[i][j+1][k]+ez[i][j][k]);
                ihxh[ixh][j][k]=ihxh[ixh][j][k]+curl_e;
     fj3[j]*fk3[k]*hx[i][j][k]+fj2[j]*fk2[k]*.5*(curl_e+fi1[i]*ihxh[ixh][j][k]);
            }}}
    /////////////////////////////incident hx////////////////////////////////////
    /*for(i=ia;i<=ib;i++){
        for(k=ka;k<=kb;k++){
            hx[i][ja-1][k]=hx[i][ja-1][k]+.5*ez_inc[ja];
            hx[i][jb][k]=hx[i][jb][k]-.5*ez_inc[jb];
        }
    }*/
    //////////////////////////////update hy/////////////////////////////////////
    for(i=0;i<IE-1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<JE;j++){
            for(k=0;k<KE-1;k++){
                curl_e=(ez[i+1][j][k]-ez[i][j][k]-ex[i][j][k+1]+ex[i][j][k]);
                ihyl[i][j][k]=ihyl[i][j][k]+curl_e;
                hy[i][j][k]=fi3[i]*fk3[k]*hy[i][j][k]+fi2[i]*fk2[k]*.5*(curl_e+fj1[j]*ihyl[i][j][k]);
            }}}
    /*for(i=0;i<IE-1;i++){
        for(j=ja;j<=jb;j++){
            for(k=0;k<KE-1;k++){
                curl_e=(ez[i+1][j][k]-ez[i][j][k]-ex[i][j][k+1]+ex[i][j][k]);
                hy[i][j][k]=fi3[i]*fk3[k]*hy[i][j][k]+fi2[i]*fk2[k]*.5*curl_e;
            }}}
    for(i=0;i<IE-1;i++){
        for(j=jb+1;j<JE;j++){
            jyh=JE-j-1;
            for(k=0;k<KE-1;k++){
                curl_e=(ez[i+1][j][k]-ez[i][j][k]-ex[i][j][k+1]+ex[i][j][k]);
                ihyh[i][jyh][k]=ihyh[i][jyh][k]+curl_e;
                hy[i][j][k]=fi3[i]*fk3[k]*hy[i][j][k]+fi2[i]*fk2[k]*.5*(curl_e+fj1[j]*ihyh[i][jyh][k]);
            }}}*/
    /////////////////////////////incident hy////////////////////////////////////
    /*for(j=ja;j<=jb;j++){
        for(k=ka;k<=kb;k++){
            hy[ia-1][j][k]=hy[ia-1][j][k]-.5*ez_inc[j];
            hy[ib][j][k]  =hy[ib][j][k]  +.5*ez_inc[j];
        }
    }*/
    /////////////////////////////update hz////////////////////////////////////////
    for(i=0;i<IE-1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<JE-1;j++){
            for(k=0;k<ka;k++){
                curl_e=(ex[i][j+1][k]-ex[i][j][k]-ey[i+1][j][k]+ey[i][j][k]);
                ihzl[i][j][k]=ihzl[i][j][k]+curl_e;
                hz[i][j][k]=fi3[i]*fj3[j]*hz[i][j][k]+fi2[i]*fj2[j]*.5*         (curl_e+fk1[k]*ihzl[i][j][k]);
            }}}
    for(i=0;i<IE-1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<JE-1;j++){
            for(k=ka;k<=kb;k++){
                curl_e=(ex[i][j+1][k]-ex[i][j][k]-ey[i+1][j][k]+ey[i][j][k]);
                hz[i][j][k]=fi3[i]*fj3[j]*hz[i][j][k]+fi2[i]*fj2[j]*.5*curl_e;
            }}}
    for(i=0;i<IE-1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<JE-1;j++){
            for(k=kb+1;k<KE;k++){
                kzh=KE-k-1;
                curl_e=(ex[i][j+1][k]-ex[i][j][k]-ey[i+1][j][k]+ey[i][j][k]);
                ihzh[i][j][kzh]=ihzh[i][j][kzh]+curl_e;
                hz[i][j][k]=fi3[i]*fj3[j]*hz[i][j][k]+fi2[i]*fj2[j]*.5*(curl_e+fk1[k]*ihzh[i][j][kzh]);
            }}} 

}//********************************END OF FDTD*******************************////////////




}
```

As you can see my code is full of some for loops that acts on some matrixes how can I ignore this for loops for example can I use functions instead of writing that for loops.I really appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: You should probably ask this at [http://programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) and tag the question as `code-reviews`. Other than that, define helper functions to cut down on copy'n'paste.

Comment: Its totally off-topic, since there's no definitive answer. Several comments: triple-level pointers is a no-no, variable names must be descriptive (and no, "array" or "***sx" are not. "pi" though is), structure your code so that every function will fit your screen (or less), and try not to have too many memory allocations (if you're not an experienced programmer - reduce it to minimum).

Comment: Your code is mostly C. Why do you even use C++?

Comment: @Alex or just post it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If I had to work with your code I would find you and murder you.

Comment: @dbaupp: Thanks! That's what I tried to find but got lost in the multitude of stackexchange sites. :)

Comment: How do you make sense of it? sweat. Flagged to move to programmers stackexchange.

Comment: OP certainly qualifies this: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer

Comment: No doubt this code has been generated from Matlab or Mathematica or something

Comment: @sehe Matlab can do this job too but the speed of it is very low I use matlab just for post processing (plot,...)and I have no idea about Mathematica because I never used it before

Answer (score 8):

Download an existing library like GLM, Eigen, Boost.UBLAS which provides matrix functions for you.

Also, use `std::vector`.

Comment: This code is just an example. The dimension of matrixes that I use are about 400*400*400 I really afraid of segmentation fault problem.Can  these libraries work with such huge matrixes.Notice that for parallel case I use matrixes with dimensions such as 400*50*400.

Comment: There's no reason why these libraries should be unable to handle matrices of the same size. (for a 400x400x400 array of doubles, you only need 512MB of memory anyway. Shouldn't be a problem)

Comment: @user1285136: They will likely be far more efficient at it than you are. Your C-style memory management is much more likely to fail than a modern C++ library, and they will have more efficient algorithms for things like multiplication of large matrices.

Comment: Can I use them with mpi library?

Comment: @user1285136: How would I even know what library that is? And why don't you just goddamn try it? In the intervening time, you could have easily determined this.

Comment: @DeadMG MPI is message passing interface library for parallel processing .because my programming skill is very low and testing those libraries for me, is hard.

Answer (score 4):

Please start by using words for variables rather than single or double letters. My instinct were I ever to come across code like that would be to carefully rename things towards what they were. or junk it and rewrite it if that proved impossible.

Answer (score 3):

Three things immediately come to mind.

First, longer, more descriptive variable names and/or constants.

Things like `l`, `m` and `n` do not tell me anything about the variable.

Secondly, more comments. Every block that does something significant should have a comment stating at a high level *what* it does (not *how,* other than very generally, I can read the code to find that out).

Thirdly, we don't have a shortage of function prototypes so you don't have to put just about every single statement into `main()` :-)

If a single function takes up more than about fifty lines (as an example), it's probably too long, and should be calling more sub-functions).

Comment: I would upvote this but for recommending commenting: If you feel your code needs a comment in order to be understandable, rewrite it so that I can understand it without an explanation.

Comment: @sbi, comments tell you what and possibly why, code tells you how.

Comment: Actually, IMO that's wrong. The function's name should tell me _what_ (`PerformHyperReduction()`), and a comment, if necessary at all, (yes, I, too, sometimes add comments to my code) should tell me _how_: `// implements Przlbwlszk's 2nd hyper-reduction algorithm`. Whenever I feel like I need to add a comment explaining _what_ the next few lines do, I instead move them into an aptly named (inlined) function.

Answer (score 0):

multiple ideas to your code.

1st one that pops to my mind, why do you not use matlab for such mathematical simulations?

2nd i am a student in electrical engineering and thus do know my fair share about electromagnetic waves. i would really have thought that if i see code that simulates waves i would recognise at least the vast outline of it. but i dont see anything in your code that tells me something. to improve that:

- change your variable names, it might be ennerving sometimes to have long variable names, but it will totally be worth it if you want to re-read your code later on and change it.
- `double ***gax=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE);` you really shouldnt use triple pointers.
- to get rid of some of the loops, write functions that do the loop for you, give the functions a distinct name that tells you exactly what it does. this will clean up most of your code.

Comment: The problem of matlab is its speed.c++ is very faster than it.and double ***gax=alloc3d(IE,JE,KE); is the only one way that I found for solving segmentation fault problem.